# Parsing HashMap to Json

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

Here is the HashMap I'm trying to parse:

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();  
map.put("bowser", "b=mozilla");  
map.put("car", "car=Ford");
map.put("model","model=Mustang");
map.put("Year", 2014);
map.put("dealer", "Dealer=AKHI");
```

First I've tried Gson and then Jackson but both of them have a common problem., 
They parse "=" to "\u003d"

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

try {
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
    System.out.println("---------------------Parsed HashMap---------------------------:"+json); 
}
catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output I get is :

---------------------Parsed HashMap---------------------------:   {"dealer":"Dealer\u003dAKHI","car":"car\u003dFord","Year":2014,"model":"model\u003dMustang","bowser":"b\u003dmozilla"}

I've been through few other blogs and see that there is a glitch in the API but is there any way we could fix this here with may be some other method.

Comment: Which version of library are you using? I am using `Jackson` 2.2.2 and it serialize it properly: `{"dealer":"Dealer=AKHI","car":"car=Ford","Year":2014,"model":"model=Mustang","bowser":"b=mozilla"}`.

Comment: In here I've used Gson but I've used jackson as well but I had similar problems

Comment: Quick comment on terminology: no, you are not "parsing": that means reading JSON content, producting something else. You are trying to create JSON: generate or write JSON out of Maps. Beyond that, why do you care? JSON generators are allowed to use escaping any way they want, and output you get is legal and accurate representation of input you give. Even if, in case of GSON, it is not strictly necessary to use that escaping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `=` sign is encoded to `\u003d`. Hence you need to use `disableHtmlEscaping()`.

You can use

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

Comment: Purely out of interest, would escaping the "=" character to "\=" work?

Comment: @Gorb cant understand wat you mean to say?

Comment: Would escaping the value, i.e. by using a backslash (which is the escape character in Java) also fix this behaviour?

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

This works good for me, I'm able to parse = sign as well.

Thanks Niks

Comment: wlc @Akhilendra.If the solution work thn select as correct answer

Comment: @NiksTyagi: I just did, I'm a newbie to Stackoverflow. 
Just getting used to things... :)